# Log4j2 creating additional files from appenders

Tags: logging, log4j, log4j2

I have two classes MyClass1 and MyClass2 in two separate packages, package1 and package2 respectively. These classes are meant to be used separately with no interaction across packages.

Now, for logging, I have two FastFileAppender's configured in my log4j2 config (each writing to MyClass1.log and MyClass2.log). I have two loggers(with name= package1 and package2) each referring to its own file appender.
The issue I am facing is, if I run MyClass1, then the logger creates both the log files one of which (in this case, MyClass2.log) is empty.

Is there a way to tell the manager to instantiate only the used appender so that it does not create additional empty files?

Below is my log4j2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
        <FastFile name="file1" fileName="MyClass1.log" append="false">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </FastFile>
        <FastFile name="file2" fileName="MyClass2.log" append="false">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </FastFile>
    </appenders>
    <loggers>
        <root level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="Console" />
        </root>
        <logger name="package1" level="TRACE"
            additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="Console" level="INFO" />
            <appender-ref ref="file1" level="TRACE" />
        </logger>
        <logger name="package2" level="TRACE"
            additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="Console" level="INFO" />
            <appender-ref ref="file2" level="TRACE" />
        </logger>
    </loggers>
</configuration>
```